How to Handle Null Values in Mapping with jOOQ's row() Method in Select Queries?
I'm using jOOQ for database querying, and I have a situation where I'm mapping fields using the row() method within a select query like this:
.select(
    // Other fields...
    .row(MyRecord).mapping(MyMapper::toDto)
    // Other fields...
)

However, due to left joins in my query, the all fields of the MyRecord object can sometimes be null. Is there a way to avoid mapping if the left part is null and simply return null for the field instead?
I know I could use a lambda function within the mapper instead of a method reference, but I'm wondering if there's a more convenient way to handle this scenario. Any suggestions or best practices for handling null values in mapping with the row() method in jOOQ select queries would be appreciated.
Maybe is there a method like row(MyRecord, Predicate) which can return null if the predicate is false? Or other clean way to avoid mapping in case of null values.
Thank you.

There's a utility that you may use for this case: Functions::nullOnAllNull. Specifically:
.row(...).mapping(nullOnAllNull(MyMapper::toDto))


I doesn't work because generated TableRecord is never null, even it has all fields as null.

@Artem: I'm sorry, I don't understand why "it doesn't work" from your example. Perhaps, you could provide a complete example that isn't simplified or omits relevant utilities (e.g. the toDto method)?
