Jooq - How to query Nullable 1:1 relationships with Nested Records (Row) and Ad-Hoc Conversion
When using jooq with Nested Records (see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/) and Ad-Hoc Conversion (see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/coming-from-jpa/from-jpa-manytoone/), i could not find a good example for the case of processing a "Nullable 1:1 relationships".
Following example:

A product can have an "editor", but the editor could also be NULL (no editor)

I have tried it out and got it to work, but it seems a little bit boilerplate.
...
row(
    PRODUCT.editor().USERID,
    PRODUCT.editor().FIRSTNAME,
    PRODUCT.editor().LASTNAME
).convertFrom(r -> (r.value1() == null) ? null : mapping(UserDTO::new).apply(r)),
...

Note that we do not need to define the leftJoin here explicitly because jooq would use a Left Join (left outer join for mariadb) per default for the Path-Expression (see "Default JOIN type": https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), because we have the "nullable parent" case.
If the USERID column returns NULL in the joined result, we can be sure that there is no User-Row in the User-Table matching the Foreign-Key.
This can be accomplished with the (r.value1() == null) ? null : ... clause that returns NULL when the first column (USERID) returns NULL.

Is there a jooq-function to automatically resolve NULL-Values on row() without the explicit conversion seen here (maybe with help of the Path-Expression that contains the FK-Information)?
Is my way of doing this the recommended way?


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78263705/how-to-handle-null-values-in-mapping-with-jooqs-row-method-in-select-queries

Use Functions::nullOnAllNull:
.row(...).mapping(nullOnAllNull(UserDTO::new))

Alternatively, if you only need to check the ID, you could write your utility like this (repeating for all necessary degrees of Function[N]):
public static final <T1, T2, R extends I> Function2<T1, T2, R> nullOnIdNull(
    Function2<? super T1, ? super T2, ? extends R> function
) {
    return (t1, t2) -> { 
        R result = function.apply(t1, t2);
        return result.getId() == null ? null : result;
    }
}

And now, let all your DTOs implement this, or a similar interface:
public interface I {
    Long getId();
}


Hi Lukas,
thank you! that would indeed be the perfect method for my described use-case.
This answers the question so i mark it as solved. My (full) use-case (which for he sake of shortness i left out here) does contain a "multiset" within the "row". And because the multiset would return an empty-list when it does not find anything (instead of null) the nullOnAllNull function would not be usable for this specific use-case. I guess what i need would be an "nullOnIdNull" method, that only processes the identifying-field(s) and not all fields.

@funkrusher You can write your own utility that does exactly that

@funkrusher: I wrote a simple example showing how this could be done.

Hi Lukas,
Thanks again for the valuable input. I will try this.
I need to think about the "composite identity"-case a bit. I wonder if the getId() function may need to return a fully typed RecordX<T1, T2, ...> to support the case of a "composite identity". When the getId function returns a RecordX<>, then the nullOnIdNull function could check all values in the RecordX for NULL (to support composite Identity). An advantage of this approach is, that i could also use the getId() method in my AbstractDAO for other things.

i would need to take care to not pollute the Pojos/DTOs with Jooq-specific classes like RecordX though. Sometimes Tools like Swagger automatically pull those in and cause problems. But i will try around with it :) I had a DTO return a JooqRecord accidentally sometimes and that was too much for swagger, as it tried to pull the complete class-hierarchy for the JooqRecord :) Lets see, thanks for the input for sure.

Another possible way to solve this can be a self-written early-exit RecordMapper that makes the NULL-Check as early as possible to avoid unnecessary instantiation.
public class FkJooqHelper {

    private static class NullOnFirstNullRecordMapper<R extends Record, E> implements RecordMapper<R, E> {
        private final Function<R, E> mapper;

        public NullOnFirstNullRecordMapper(Function<R, E> mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        @Override
        public @Nullable E map(R r) {
            return (r.getValue(0) == null) ? null : mapper.apply(r);
        }
    }

    public static <R extends Record, E> RecordMapper<R, E> nullOnFirstNull(Function<R, E> mapper) {
        return new NullOnFirstNullRecordMapper<>(mapper);
    }
}

This way we can avoid boilerplate and the syntax is (somewhat) self-explaining.

if the first field has a null-value the whole result will be null.

...
row(
    PRODUCT.editor().USERID,
    PRODUCT.editor().FIRSTNAME,
    PRODUCT.editor().LASTNAME
).convertFrom(nullOnFirstNull(mapping(UserDTO::create))),
...

I decided for this solution, because i think it is best, to make the NULL-Check as early as possible (before the mapping has been executed), to avoid potential instantiation of DTOs with Empty-Lists/Hash-Maps that may also cost  Memory.
Also i think that first instantiating the DTO and afterwards checking the DTO if it contains NULL-Values is the wrong place for checking, because the DTO is not directly coupled to the database / datamodel anymore (not like the records).
By using a RecordMapper-class we profit from the already existing default apply-method on the RecordMapper-Interface, which will automatically pass the Parameter of the convertFrom function deeper down (because of default). This helps to avoid passing down this parameter explicitly.
Disadvantages of this approach:

does not automatically detect if there is really a "first value" field available. But practically this case should not be possible because there would always need to be at least one field in the select, selected for selection (which would be typechecked by jooq already)
developer needs to know, which field he needs to set as the first-field in his select (the foreign-key field!). Developer needs to know what he does.
its not really clear from the code what is exactly checked for NULL (the Record or the Mapping-Result) without knowing whats going on under the hood.

